# Extracting data from span itemprop on web page

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to build a web scraper using vba. I want to extract the data ( street-address, postal-code and locality) from website to worksheet but I have problems.

```
<li id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMainCol_CompanyDetailsInfoData1_liAddress" class="i-location" itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Address">

                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMainCol_CompanyDetailsInfoData1_aShowOnMap" onclick="openMapTis(517648, 57522, 'KOVINARSTVO IVANETIČ d.o.o.|Omota    8 |Semič');">
                            <span itemprop="street-address">Omota    8</span>, <span itemprop="settlement">Omota</span>, <span itemprop="postal-code">8333</span> <span itemprop="locality">Semič</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

Sub CompanyData()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim ht As HTMLDocument

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

'searching web address

ie.navigate ("https://www.bizi.si")

Do Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
     DoEvents
Loop

'searching company

Set ht = ie.document

ht.getElementsByTagName("Input").Item("ctl00$Search1$tbSearchWhat").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Podatki").Range("A1").Value

'click on search result

Set elems = ht.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each elem In elems
    If elem.className = "i-search" Then
       elem.Click
       Exit For
    End If
Next

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:06"))

Set AllHyperLinks = ht.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks

        If hyper_link.innerText = Range("A1").Value Then
            hyper_link.Click
            Exit For
    End If
Next

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:06"))

gf = ht.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
gf = Range("B2")



End Sub
```

I want to extract the data ( street-address, postal-code and locality) from website to worksheet.

Comment: You should explain in more detail what exactly are the problems you have. Where in your code does the problem occur? What is the error message, if any, that is given? How much investigation of the problem have you done yourself (e.g. by putting in debug.print statements in your code)? These would be a great help to your readers, and mean they are more able - and willing - to help you..

Comment: Problem start with gf = ht.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
gf = Range("B2") I want to extract data on excel sheet. It work ok to this sentence.

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting an error? Have you printed out `gf` to see what it contains? Is it what you expect it to be? Also, if you're trying to export data to excel, it should be `Range("B2").value = gf` and not the other way around.

Comment: I changed like you suggested (Range("B2").value = gf) - thanx and now I getting some results but this data is wrong.  <span itemprop="street-address">Omota    8</span> - on the sheet is supposed to be the result Omota 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page actually constructs a queryString url using the company name; So, you only need to add the company name to the end of a base url (rather than enter on a page). You can also just use xhr rather than slow browser (and url encode the company name).

I use [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to match on the appropriate table elements for the address. css selectors are applied via [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of [HTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument).

The regex is just to do some string tidying to remove excess whitespace.

---

**Internet Explorer:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CompanyData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, re As Object

    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Pattern = "\s{2,}"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.bizi.si/iskanje?q=" & ws.Range("A1").Value

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        ws.Range("B1").Value = re.Replace(Join$(Array(.document.querySelector("td.item a").innerText, .document.querySelector("td.item + td.item").innerText), ", "), Chr$(32))

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**[XHR: xmlhttp request](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/)**

```
Public Sub CompanyData2()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, ws As Worksheet, re As Object

    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Pattern = "\s{2,}"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.bizi.si/iskanje?q=" & Application.EncodeURL(ws.Range("A1").Value), False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    ws.Range("B1").Value = re.Replace(Join$(Array(html.querySelector("td.item a").innerText, html.querySelector("td.item + td.item").innerText), ", "), Chr$(32))
End Sub
```

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library